# Problem with an overlay loader relative to a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an **Overlay Loader** relative to a `div`. But the problem is that, as you can see in the snippet, as I add a some other tags such as `<h1>` and `<p>` in the example, it pushes the overlay downward. But I'm trying to make overlay all over the parent `div` and it content.

```css
.myTestDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blueviolet;
}

.spinner-box {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(1, 130, 250, 0.315);
}

.pulse-container {
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.pulse-bubble {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3f90f9;
}

.pulse-bubble-1 {
  animation: pulse .4s ease 0s infinite alternate;
}

.pulse-bubble-2 {
  animation: pulse .4s ease .2s infinite alternate;
}

.pulse-bubble-3 {
  animation: pulse .4s ease .4s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: .25;
    transform: scale(.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="myTestDiv">
  <h1>A heading</h1>
  <p>A Paragraph</p>
  <div class="spinner-box">
    <div class="pulse-container">
      <div class="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-1"></div>
      <div class="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-2"></div>
      <div class="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
Overlay its now over any text.

```css
.myTestDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blueviolet;
}

.spinner-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(1, 130, 250, 0.315);
}

.pulse-container {
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.pulse-bubble {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3f90f9;
}

.pulse-bubble-1 {
  animation: pulse .4s ease 0s infinite alternate;
}

.pulse-bubble-2 {
  animation: pulse .4s ease .2s infinite alternate;
}

.pulse-bubble-3 {
  animation: pulse .4s ease .4s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: .25;
    transform: scale(.75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="myTestDiv">
  <h1>A heading</h1>
  <p>A Paragraph</p>
  <h1>aaasdfsdfsdfsdfsdfaaa</h1>
  <div class="spinner-box">
    <div class="pulse-container">
      <div class="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-1"></div>
      <div class="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-2"></div>
      <div class="pulse-bubble pulse-bubble-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you dude @Lukas